# Unable to loop out event listeners for menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign some scrolling destinations for a menu for my one page application, the idea of this script is to prevent myself from repeating the same code over and over, but it's not quite working out the way I want it to.

Basically what happens is that `destinations[i]` becomes undefined and therefore I cannot access `.dest` of it. When I try just to console log `destinations[i]` I do get the desired result, but when I then go to click the buttons I can't scroll to anything since nothing is defined as the `.offset` value.

Why doesn't the value of `destinations[i]` remain after the loop and what can I do to make this work as intended?

```
var destinations = [
    {class: '.home', dest: $('html, body')},
    {class: '.lunch', dest: $('#menu-wrapper')},
    {class: '.catering', dest: $('#catering-wrapper')},
    {class: '.renting', dest: $('#renting-wrapper')},
    {class: '.karaoke', dest: $('#karaoke-wrapper')},
    {class: '.contact', dest: $('#site-footer')}
],
destLength = destinations.length,
i;

for (i = 0; i < destLength; i++) {
    $(destinations[i].class + ' a').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: destinations[i].dest.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use functions, they have the scope you need:

```
var destinations = [
    {"class": '.home', dest: $('html, body')},
    {"class": '.lunch', dest: $('#menu-wrapper')},
    {"class": '.catering', dest: $('#catering-wrapper')},
    {"class": '.renting', dest: $('#renting-wrapper')},
    {"class": '.karaoke', dest: $('#karaoke-wrapper')},
    {"class": '.contact', dest: $('#site-footer')}
];

destinations.forEach(function(dest, i){ 
    $(dest['class'] + ' a').on('click', function() {
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: dest.dest.offset().top
      }, 1000);
    });
});
```

forEach() also leaves no extra vars hanging around, gives you an index for var free, doesn't need a length, and looks a little cleaner to boot.

edit: added old-ie-safe prop access for "class", which is a reserved word in JS...

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure without seeing the surrounding code, but if you have the `var` in front of the declaration of `destinations` and it's inside of the loop, then `destinations` is deleted as soon as the loop is executed.  See [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it)

Answer (score 0):

As @dandavis suggested, `foreach()` seems more logical here, but for your code, when you loop until `destLength` it gives you the number of elements in `destinations[]`, but elements numbering starts from 0, so you should use `destLength-1`

```
var destinations = [
    {class: '.home', dest: $('html, body')},
    {class: '.lunch', dest: $('#menu-wrapper')},
    {class: '.catering', dest: $('#catering-wrapper')},
    {class: '.renting', dest: $('#renting-wrapper')},
    {class: '.karaoke', dest: $('#karaoke-wrapper')},
    {class: '.contact', dest: $('#site-footer')}
],
destLength = destinations.length,
i;

for (i = 0; i < (destLength-1); i++) {
    $(destinations[i].class + ' a').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: destinations[i].dest.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    });
}
```